# Is it possible to run all of Tor wirelessly connecting phones like a meshnet?

Tags: security, censorship, mobile

I've used an app called tincan on android that allows users to wirelessly connect to pass messages around in a decentralized manner. I know it's already possible to run [hidden services  on android](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/create-anonymous-wikileaks-mirror-on-your-android-device/)

i feel like this would be a great way for people in oppressive regimes to have access to information.

and a great way to avoid awful ISPS (comcast).

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking about. Could you clarify your question? I close it for now and it can be reopened after you edited it.